# Reading CSV data from NodeJS into AngularJS shows only promise object with data $$state. How to access this data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, csv

**Disclaimer:** I am a C programmer and *very* new to AngularJS (more like push into it), and I am using this code structure because of the previous guy. Also, there are like a million similar questions, but not exactly what code I have. So diving in:

**TASK:** I need to read a CSV file, get some data from it. Depending on field values, display a button in HTML of a specific color (i.e value > 4, then show green button, value < 4 show red button).

**What I have done:** So, I have read the CSV file using fs in NodeJS, then got the data into AngularJS using a Factory.

**Problem:** In AngularJS, I get a promise object ([object Object] in console). I need to access the values which I can see in this object. I have spent a better part of a week looking at this.

Backend Server - router.js

```
myRouter.route('/')

    .get(function (req, res) {
        var username = req.decoded.email;
        var csvDir = path.join(dataPath, 'mypath/' + username.substring(0, username.lastIndexOf("@")) + '.csv');

        console.log('file path in myRouter:', csvDir);

        fs.readFile(csvDir, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            console.log(data);
            res.json(data);
        });

    })
```

myFactory.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')

  .factory('myFactory', ['$resource', 'baseURL', function ($resource, baseURL) {

    return $resource(baseURL + "myRouter/", null, null);

  }]);
```

AngularJS - controller.js

```
var initializeDisplay = function () {
    console.log('Searching CSV file');
    // TODO: http get request to read CSV file content 
    $scope.myData = FeatureFactory.get({}, function () {
         console.log($scope.myData);
     });

    // feedbackData.$promise.then(function (data) {
    //     console.log(data);
    // }, function (error) {
    //     console.error(data);
    // })
    console.log('Processing CSV file');

    updateDisplay(); // To display correct color button in HTML
};
```

Advice, solutions are desperately welcome :)

```
T {0: "I", 1: "D", 2: ",", 3: "S", 4: "t", 5: "o", 6: "r", 7: "y", 8: ",", 9: "S", 10: "i", 11: "t", 12: "u", 13: "a", 14: "t", 15: "i", 16: "o", 17: "n", 18: ",", 19: "T", 20: "a", 21: "s", 22: "k", 23: " ", 24: "A", 25: "c", 26: "t", 27: "i", 28: "o", 29: "n", 30: ",", 31: "R", 32: "e", 33: "s", 34: "u", 35: "l", 36: "t", 37: ",", 38: "E", 39: "y", 40: "e", 41: " ", 42: "g", 43: "a", 44: "z", 45: "e", 46: ",", 47: "V", 48: "o", 49: "i", 50: "c", 51: "e", 52: " ", 53: "E", 54: "n", 55: "e", 56: "r", 57: "g", 58: "y", 59: ",", 60: "W", 61: "M", 62: "E", 63: "I", 64: "
", 65: "↵", 66: "1", 67: ",", 68: "1", 69: ",", 70: "4", 71: ",", 72: "3", 73: ",", 74: "2", 75: ",", 76: "1", 77: ",", 78: "2", 79: ",", 80: "3", $promise: c, $resolved: true}
0: "I"
1: "D"
2: ","
3: "S"
4: "t"
5: "o"
6: "r"
7: "y"
8: ","
9: "S"
10: "i"
11: "t"
12: "u"
13: "a"
14: "t"
15: "i"
16: "o"
17: "n"
18: ","
19: "T"
20: "a"
21: "s"
22: "k"
23: " "
24: "A"
25: "c"
26: "t"
27: "i"
28: "o"
29: "n"
30: ","
31: "R"
32: "e"
33: "s"
34: "u"
35: "l"
36: "t"
37: ","
38: "E"
39: "y"
40: "e"
41: " "
42: "g"
43: "a"
44: "z"
45: "e"
46: ","
47: "V"
48: "o"
49: "i"
50: "c"
51: "e"
52: " "
53: "E"
54: "n"
55: "e"
56: "r"
57: "g"
58: "y"
59: ","
60: "W"
61: "M"
62: "E"
63: "I"
64: ""
65: "↵"
66: "1"
67: ","
68: "1"
69: ","
70: "4"
71: ","
72: "3"
73: ","
74: "2"
75: ","
76: "1"
77: ","
78: "2"
79: ","
80: "3"
$promise: c {$$state: {…}}
$resolved: true
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: can you please add the entire object you got in console to the question?

Comment: @Sravan: edited question to add the object

Comment: CSV files should be sent as `text/csv`. The `$resource` service is not appropriate for text resources. Instead use the `$http` service.

Comment: @georgeawg: oh! ok.. could you please explain this a little more and link to some code? I have not read this anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

Usually AngularJS is using [$q provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) for implementation of promisses.
It's expected to have promise Object in the response since the fetching data from Node.JS is async operation.

Your factory myFactory is actually using $resource provider, there is an example in AngularJS documentation

```
var User = $resource('/users/:userId', {userId: '@id'});
User.get({userId: 123}).$promise.then(function(user) {
  user.abc = true;
  user.$save();
});
```

More details at:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

In your case it should be:

```
var initializeDisplay = function () {
    console.log('Searching CSV file');
    // TODO: http get request to read CSV file content 
     FeatureFactory.get({}).$promise
    .then(function(data){
      $scope.myData=data;
     updateDisplay(); // To display correct color button in HTML
    });
};
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I am still a little lost about the $resource part. Could you clarify how I should use it in this particular case?

Comment: It should work if you keep your factory the same as it's in the question, just initializeDisplay function should be changed. I hope this helps. Also for debugging and better support, it would be great if you can provide codepen or something like that.

Comment: This did not work. I still get the object same as the one in the question.